# Image to Sketch using HTML 5

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I want to convert an image into the sketch using Html 5 or jquery or asp.net. Moreover i want to add the image save functionality to it. Please share some code. thanks in advance

Comment: what does it means "into the sketch"? and what code have you tried so far?

Comment: From sketch you mean grayscale?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete source code which converts the image into grayscale by using the 2d canvas api oh html5. But be sure to use the browser which supports html5 canvas.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Global variables
        var picWidth = 400; // width of the canvas
        var picHeight = 400; // height of the canvas
        var picLength = picWidth * picHeight; // number of chunks
        var myImage = new Image(); // Create a new blank image.

        // Load the image and display it.
        function displayImage() {

            // Get the canvas element.
            canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

            // Make sure you got it.
            if (canvas.getContext) {

                // Specify 2d canvas type.
                ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                // When the image is loaded, draw it.
                myImage.onload = function () {
                    // Load the image into the context.
                    ctx.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0);

                    // Get and modify the image data.
                    getColorData();

                    // Put the modified image back on the canvas.
                    putColorData();
                }

                // Define the source of the image.
                // This file must be on your machine in the same folder as this web page.
                myImage.src = "kestral.png";
            }
        }

        function getColorData() {
            myImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 400, 400);
            // Loop through data.
            for (var i = 0; i < picLength * 4; i += 4) {

                // First bytes are red bytes.        
                // Get red value.
                var myRed = myImage.data[i];

                // Second bytes are green bytes.
                // Get green value.
                var myGreen = myImage.data[i + 1];

                // Third bytes are blue bytes.
                // Get blue value.
                var myBlue = myImage.data[i + 2];

                // Fourth bytes are alpha bytes
                // We don't care about alpha here.
                // Add the three values and divide by three.
                // Make it an integer.
                myGray = parseInt((myRed + myGreen + myBlue) / 3);

                // Assign average to red, green, and blue.
                myImage.data[i] = myGray;
                myImage.data[i + 1] = myGray;
                myImage.data[i + 2] = myGray;
            }
        }
        function putColorData() {

            ctx.putImageData(myImage, 0, 0);
        }
        function noPhoto() {
            alert("Please put a .png file in this folder.");
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="displayImage()">
    <h1>
     Codeheaven.org Example (Image to Grayscale uisng html5 canvas)
    </h1>
    <p>
      The original image is on the left and the modified image is on the right.
    </p>
    <img id="myPhoto" src="kestral.PNG" onerror="noPhoto()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400">
    </canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Give the path of your image in img src property. and also set the proper width and height of image according to your image size.